# How fast can a panda run?

Tags: zoology

Pandas are going extinct, mostly due to habitat destruction. This leads me to the question:  How fast can an average adult panda run? (more specifically Giant Panda)

Comment: How does panda's habitat destruction lead you to wonder about their top speed?

Comment: @Remi.b habitat destruction -> pandas dying  -> animals dying -> being prey -> escaping predators -> running -> running speed

Comment: Adult pandas don't have predators. But anyway. The question is valid without needing justification for your interest :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that in comparison to a North American bear species, giant pandas would not give chase for very long as they prefer to move slowly.  Recent research into giant panda biology indicates that the foraging speed of a giant panda is 50 feet an hour.  Their metabolism is very slow, lower than a three toed sloth.  Their entire way of life is slow movement so considering all that, I would say that you might be able to *outlast* them in a run.
http://www.livescience.com/51505-giant-panda-metabolism.html